# How to disable content editing to users other than content owners and super admin in Sitecore workflow

Tags: experience-editor, content-editor, security, workflow, editor-user-permissions

We need to disable 'lock and edit' option for authors other than content owner who initiated the workflow. I able to achieve this by changing the below settings in Sitecore.config

- RequireLockBeforeEditing as False
- AutomaticLockOnSave as True

After these changes, the item is locked on saving the item. If other content author tried to edit the same item, the item shown warnings says "The Item is locked by the locked person who did the changes at first". Also the item is in Edit workflow state and shown the link to content owner "Ready For Review". If the content owner clicked the link, an email will be triggered to approvers. This is fine. But,  subsequently the lock is also removed from the item when the workflow state is getting changed.

We have 2 level of approvers.
Approver 1 cannot edit but they can do verify the content and approve.
Approver2 can Edit and Approve the content.

So, during "Awaiting Approval" state, both approver1 and approver2 can edit and approve the content though "lock and edit" option is hidden. But we should not allow the Approver 1 to edit the content.

Is there any way to restrict the edit access to all users other than content owner who initiates the workflow and approver2(Super admin)? Most importantly, we should not use security access rights

Any help would be highly appreciated..

Comment: You can achieve this by adding a new custom unlock button and a role for unlocking items and giving permission only to approver 2 on the new button.

Comment: Is it possible from OOTB without customization?

Comment: I don't think so